# amchart legend missing in iphone6

Tags: javascript, mobile, amcharts

Having an issue where an amPieChart's legend isn't showing up on our website when run on iphone6.  Works fine on iphone6+ and others but on iphone6 it's just empty space.

```
"legend": {
    "divId": "piChartLegendDiv",
    "position": "bottom",
    "autoMargins": false,
    "labelText": "[[title]]",
    "valueWidth": "0",
    "markerType": "circle",
}
```

The mobile stuff:

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6 / 7 / 8 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .volume-custom-footer {
        display: flex;

        .card-footer {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }

    .hidePad {
        display: none;
    }
    .opta-avatar {
        height: 65px !important;
        width: 65px !important;
    }
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .card-body-portrait{
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .your-team-avatar-rsp {
        width: 75px !important;
        height: 75px !important;
    }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {
}
```

What can I try to get this working or at least get closer to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript section for the pie chart itself there was a piece:

```
                       "responsive": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "addDefaultRules": false,
                            "rules": [
                                {
                                    "maxWidth": 400,
                                    "overrides": {
                                        "legend": {
                                            "enabled": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

I apparently just needed to set enabled to true.  Now screens with low resolution (iphone 5/6) show the legend even if it's cut off.